# Can I export the SQL query results from Netezza?

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, netezza

We want to run a query in the Netezza IDE and export the results in the form of a CSV file. Is there any API which would let us do the same, using a shell or some other script?

Is there any shell available with Netezza which anyone knows about, using which I can run an SQL query and get the results in a text file or a CSV file (preferred)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have powershell among your tags, I am assuming you need a tool that works under Windows. The command line client for Netezza - nzsql - is not available for Windows but there is a couple of third-party command line sql clients/shells which you can use with with Netezza:

- [jisql](http://www.xigole.com/software/jisql/jisql.jsp), JDBC client; the parameters are the same as in SQuirreL
- [dbish](http://search.cpan.org/~tlowery/DBI-Shell-11.93/dbish.PL), a perl-based ODBC client; if your ODBC DSN is called NZ, the command line would be

`dbish dbi:ODBC:NZ user password`

Both tools have options to output results as CSV files.

Answer (score 2):

Aginity Workbench for Netezza allows you to do that easily. The application is an IDE that runs under Windows. Also, it gives you a command line interface so that it could be launched from a cmd or bat file on Windows. You can use either ODBC or OleDb driver for connecting to Netezza.
More information here http://www.aginity.com

Comment: I often run into "out of memory" errors when exporting large (>1 million row) datasets via Aginity. It's definitely the easiest way to go for small ad-hoc requests though.

Comment: If you use the Aginity Workbench command like parameters, you can avoid using the GUI, which should resolve "out of memory" errors. Use the menu option Tools -> Workbench Command Line Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Netezza has an ODBC driver that you should be able to use to have a client application pull data out of NZ.

You could also write a shell script that uses the nzsql command line query tool to save data into a file. I tend to write the SQL as a concatenation of string fields and the comma character:

```
SELECT FIELD1||','||FIELD2
```

This does the concatenation in-database which is often faster than the client app doing it, since you can take advantage of the MPP nature of the database.

I have successfully used the ODBC connection via powershell to pull data out of Netezza:

```
$conn = new-object system.data.odbc.odbcconnection
$conn.connectionstring = "Driver={NetezzaSQL};servername=*SERVERNAME*;port=*PORT*;database=*DATABASE*;username=*USERNAME*;password=*PASSWORD*"
$conn.open()

$cmd = new-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand
$cmd.CommandText = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\SQL\MySQLFile.sql")
$cmd.connection = $conn
$cmd.CommandTimeout = 0

$datareader = $cmd.ExecuteReader();
$stream = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\SQL\MyExportFile.csv", TRUE)

while ($datareader.Read()) { $stream.WriteLine($datareader[0]) }
$stream.close()
$datareader.close()
$conn.close()
```

The SQL itself would add the commas between the fields for me.

Comment: Running this same code, with my file paths of course, I get an error on the $stream line: Missing expression after ','.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE to unload data from Netezza to a remote system. For more information, look at the Netezza Data Loading guide, chapter 5.

However, what I have found to be the easiest is to use SQL Squirrel and JDBC. Download SQL Squirrel here:

http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/

Get the Netezza JDBC driver and setup your connection. Once you connect to the NZ instance, go to the SQL window, write your SQL query. By default it will return only 100 rows. HOWEVER, if you right click on the results, there is an option called "Export to CSV". Choose that option and make sure the checkbox "Export entire table" is checked. This will pull out the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pipe separated data and you don't have too many fields, you can just specify it in an nzsql  command.

```
nzsql -d $DB-u $USER-pw $PASS -h $HOST -c 
   "SELECT OTLT_KEY||'|'||NHS_OTL_CD||'|'||NPD_ST||'|'||NPD_CNTY||'|' 
   FROM OTL_NHS_RLTD" > ./OTL_NHS_RLTD.psv
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this all the time in Netezza from DBVisualizer

```
@export on;

@export set filename="C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\NAMEYOURFILE.xlsx" CsvColumnDelimiter=",";

SELECT * FROM TABLE;

@export off;
```

Answer (score -1):

nzsql -d $DB-u $USER-pw $PASS -h $HOST -c 
   "SELECT OTLT_KEY||'|'||NHS_OTL_CD||'|'||NPD_ST||'|'||NPD_CNTY||'|' 
   FROM OTL_NHS_RLTD" > ./OTL_NHS_RLTD.psv

or

nzsql -d $DB-u $USER-pw $PASS -h $HOST -c 
   "SELECT OTLT_KEY||'|'||NHS_OTL_CD||'|'||NPD_ST||'|'||NPD_CNTY||'|' 
   FROM OTL_NHS_RLTD" -o /path/OTL_NHS_RLTD.psv